# Extracting and Printing multiple elements from different vectors in R

Tags: r

I have a Data Frame with over 20 columns and am trying to create a new object which returns the maximum value of one vector and also returns the value in the same row of a different vector/variable. I have been reading through many many pages/sites on extracting elements but none that I have found seem relevant in my context.

Here is the code I am using:

```
object <- DF[which.max(DF[,ColNumber]),"VARNAME"]
```

What this line of code is doing is finding the row that corresponds to the maximum value for `ColNumber` and then printing ONLY the value of `VARNAME` for that row. How can I get R to return/print BOTH `VARNAME`'s value AND the max value?

Comment: Can you show a small sample dataset with desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative using `dplyr`. First select columns of interest from dataset, mtcars. Then filter the max value of `disp`.

```
data(mtcars)
library(dplyr)
select(mtcars, mpg, disp) %>% filter(disp==max(disp))

#    mpg disp
# 1 10.4  472
```

Comment: This also worked great! I really like too that using select retains the row headings and drops the quotation marks from the character vector. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need more than one value as output, you can create a vector, something like:

```
object <- c(DF[which.max(DF[,ColNumber]),"VARNAME"],max(DF[,ColNumber]))
```

For example, taking the `mtcars` dataset,

```
data(mtcars)
object<-c(mtcars[which.max(mtcars[,3]),"mpg"],max(mtcars[,3]))
object
#[1]  10.4 472.0
```

Here `max(mtcars[,3])` gives the maximum value in the 3rd column while `mtcars[which.max(mtcars[,3]),"mpg"]` gives the value of `mpg` for the row where the 3rd column has the maximum value.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and prompt feedback! This worked great!